# Javascript- Stamping on pdf page is out of position

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext7

I am working on a program where when I start it, it will load a pdf file in my directory to a web browser. In the browser, I have the option to click on a stamp and drag and move in any position I want and stamp it on the pdf. However, once I stamped it, the stamp is not in the same position as I intended.

Below is a sample snapshot:

[image]

Below is the output of after pasting (which is not what I want) :

[image]

Javascript :

```
function divMove(e){
        var div = document.getElementById('stamp');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        //div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        //div.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        var box = div.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse_top = e.clientY;
        mouse_left = e.clientX;
        var diff_x = mouse_left - box.left;
        var diff_y = mouse_top - box.top;
        div.style.top = ((Number(div.style.top.replace("px", "")) - 1) + diff_y) +"px";
        div.style.left = ((Number(div.style.left.replace("px", "")) - 1) + diff_x) +"px";
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
            "mouse_top:" + mouse_top + "<br>mouse_left:" + mouse_left
    }

    function save(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Save",
            data: {
                mouseTop : (mouse_top/96)*1,
                mouseLeft : (mouse_left/96)*3500
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
            //use response to set stamp
                if (response != null) {
                    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary("data:application/pdf;base64, " + response);
                    loadPDFToViewer(pdfAsArray);
                    //document.getElementById("page-1").getElementsByClassName("pdfCanvas")[0].removeEventListener("click", addStamp);
                } else {
                    alert("Response is null");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Backend (java):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //String src = "C:\\Apache Tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\\myWork\\prototype\\haito.pdf";
        //String dest = "C:\\Apache Tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\\myWork\\prototype\\test.pdf";

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

        String src = p.getProperty("src");
        String dest = p.getProperty("dest");
        String imgSrc = p.getProperty("stamp");

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));


        ImageData image = ImageDataFactory.create(imgSrc);

        float w = image.getWidth();
        float h = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println("w: " + w + ", h: " + h);





        float mouseX = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("mouseTop"));
        float mouseY = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("mouseLeft"));
        System.out.println("top: " + mouseX + ", left: " + mouseY);
        //  adjusted mouse X and mouse Y position




        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(mouseX ,mouseY  ,w,h);
        PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect).setStampName(new PdfName("Approved"));
        PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(w,h));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj,doc);
        canvas.addImage(image,0,0,false);

        //canvas.getGraphicsState();
        stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());
        stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.LOCKED);
        for(int i=1;i<=doc.getNumberOfPages();i++)
        {
            doc.getPage(i).addAnnotation(stamp);
        }
        //doc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
        p.setProperty("src", dest);
        p.setProperty("dest", src);
        p.store(out, null);
        out.close();
        doc.close();
```

I've been struggling on this issue for days. I would appreciate any sort of help.
Is there a way to make the position accurate?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share your backend code that stamps the PDF based on your AJAX input? It's likely your problem is in the way the backend is using the mouse coordinates.

Comment: @davidethell ok i edited my post

Comment: @Liam The backend part is written in Java. I am using iText library for the PDF part.

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas.addImage call is passing 0, 0 as the x and y coordinates. Instead you should be passing your correctly translated coordinates from your mouse coordinates. Remember that in PDF everything is calculated from the bottom so y = 0 is the bottom of the page, not the top.

Also, there may be a better way to do your stamping using some of the examples from iText like you find here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-stamp-image-existing-pdf-and-create-anchor

```
PdfReader readerOriginalDoc = new PdfReader("src/main/resources/test.pdf");            
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(
    readerOriginalDoc, new FileOutputStream("NewStamper.pdf"));
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(1);
Image image = Image.getInstance("src/main/resources/images.jpg");
image.scaleAbsolute(50, 20);
image.setAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
image.setAnnotation(new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, 3));
content.addImage(image);
stamper.close();
```

UPDATE:
Here is an example about deciding what the PDF positioning should be based on the reported browser positioning:

```
docHeight = something; // however you choose to find the height of your document area
docWidth = something; // however you choose to find the width of your document area
mouse_top = e.clientY;
mouse_left = e.clientX;
percentTop = mouse_top / docHeight;
percentLeft = mouse_left / docWidth;
```

UPDATE: The width and height might be a specific element in your markup or the entire document. So you could get the width and height this way:

```
var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

Now pass those percents to the backend and you can work in reverse to find your PDF coordinates:

```
float percentBottom = 100.0 - Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("percentTop"));
float percentLeft = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("percentLeft"));
```

The bottom is now translated to how much percentage of the total height you need to go up from the bottom of the page to get the correct top position. The left position should be the same percentage-wise. I hope that helps.

Comment: I have looked into the link before. Unfortunately, PDFStamper is no longer valid for the latest iText version though.

Comment: So I just need to change to the right coordinates for my canvas and it should fix my issue?

Comment: Well, for sure the translation between mouse coordinates and PDF coordinates is your key. I'm pretty sure you want to try to work with percentages. So if your Y is 50 from the top that might be 20% from the top on the browser so place your stamp 80% from the bottom on the PDF. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Could you give an example on how you mean with %?

Comment: *"Remember that in PDF everything is calculated from the bottom so y = 0 is the bottom of the page, not the top."* - this merely is often so. In general, though, the origin can be anywhere inside or outside the visible page area. So in general there is a bit more to the calculation.

Comment: @davidethell I'll try it out soon and let you know. Btw, what is \ in your answer? Do you mean / instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated the answer with the correct division operator.

Comment: @davidethell I understand that some conversion needs to be done. The problem is how would I know what is the "something" in docHeight and docWidth?

Comment: I updated the code to give a sample possibility for getting the width and height of the entire document. That might vary depending on how you display the PDF to the user and whether you want the entire client area or just a specific element. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @davidethell So I need to fill in the exact position of the PDF display on browser in pixels in docHeight and docWidth ? Is that correct?

Comment: @davidethell But how does var w and var h determines size of the document display? I don't know if I inspect the elements in the browser where it has information about the pixels are accurate and could be used instead?
Also, why did you use || to determine the size ? Does it mean to choose either one of the syntax?